# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not updating

Tags: updates

I am not Ubuntu literate however noticed my 16.04 LTS is not updating 
when I try to update manually I get following message

[image: screenshot]

I would really appreciate if someone could assist me step by step assuming I know nothing about Ubuntu.

Comment: You can refer to the link [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: you have to close muon (the graphical updater) before doing the command line

Answer (score 0):

Only one program can get lock on the admin directory at a time.  Since you have the graphical software installer open, it has the lock, and your terminal command can't work.

Close the graphical installer and try your command again.  As a last ditch effort, reboot and try again.